# Situational use: Run tasks in ForkJoinPool vs. new Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads, completable-future

Since I'm trying to understand a few of the new features provided in Java 8, I came upon the following situation:

I wish to implement asynchron method calls into my application (in JavaFX). The idea was to provide/use a seperate thread for everything related to the GUI so that background tasks wont block/delay the visible output in my application.

For the background tasks, I thought about either use a pool of threads or simply run them in the main thread of the application for now. Then, I came upon the [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) used in the standard way by using the `CompletableFuture` class when doing something like this:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(task);
```

whereas `task` is a `Runnable`.

In most tutorials and the Javadoc, the `ForkJoinPool` is described as "*a pool which contains threads waiting for tasks to run*". Also, the `ForkJoinPool` is usually the size of the cores of the users machine, or doubled if hyperthreading is supported.

What advantages does the `ForkJoinPool` give me over the traditional `Thread` when I want to run a task asynchronously?

Comment: If you are impelementing a JavaFX application, you should probably look first into what JavaFX provides, like [Worker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Worker.html) and [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ForkJoinPool` is not comparable with Threads, it's rather comparable with ThreadPools. Creating a new thread by code often bad and will lead to `OutOfMemoryErrors` because it is not controlled. Depending on your use case you might need to use a `ForkJoinPool` or a different pool but make sure you use one. And by the way, all `CompletableFuture` methods have overloads that allow you pass your own thread pool.

Some benefits of ForkJoinPool,

- Already initialised for you and shutdown on the JVM shutdown, so you don't need to worry about that
- Its size can be controlled through a VM parameter
- Its perfect for compute bound task where work stealing can be beneficial, although this could be a problem depending on the case.

Comment: Don't forget that the `ForkJoinPool` comes with pre-existing load-balancing among the threads in the pool.